# Stop Event Propagation from Child Element to Parent div

Tags: javascript, angular, events

HTML showing both child and parent :

```
<div id="{{asset.id}}" data-cy="assetListEntry" class="p-3 border-bottom" [ngClass]="selected ? selectedClass : ''" (click)="onSelect()">
...

          <input appMouseStopPropagation type="checkbox" name="assetCheckbox"
          [(ngModel)]="assetStatus"
          (click)="openDialog(approvedDialogTemplate, $event); false">
...
```

When I clicked on the child  element, I do not want the (click) handler in the parent to be activated.

Contents of the child event handler:

```
  openDialog(template: TemplateRef<any>, event: PointerEvent): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    const modalConfig: ModalOptions = {
      class: 'modal-sm modal-dialog-centered',
      animated: true,
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: 'static',
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
    };
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, modalConfig);
  }
```

Content of parent event handler:

```
  onSelect(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/', this.env, 'assets', this.asset.id], { queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'});
  }
```

I have also tried:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Code for appMouseStopPropagation directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMouseStopPropagation]'
})
export class MouseStopPropagationDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
  ) {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent<MouseEvent>(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', { capture: true })
      .subscribe(event => {
console.log('catched');
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
  }
}
```

With the direct or without, same error persisted.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think it's not related to click events or something else. Can it be just a (css)  z-index problem ? When you click, both functions are executed ?

Comment: No. I clicked on the child input element and the url changed.

Comment: And if you just remove your directive  appMouseStopPropagation ?

Comment: I have tried adding ```    event.preventDefault();``` before ```event.stopPropagation();``` and also removing the directive (before posting this question).  Same error.

Comment: It does not makes sense. You should not build  a directive for this bug. 
Something else is happening here. Can you make a stackblitz or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately my company blocks the stackblitz website so I cannot run stackblitz.

Comment: Try to inspect all of the tools provided by the google chrome inspector.  Like Elements tab and Angular tab (but it have to be installed, it's an extension)

Comment: im sure this is your css problem. i created a project and test it. it works if i click exactly on checkbox and only dialog will be open.

Comment: @MojtabaNejadPoorEsmaeili thanks for the response.  I am not sure how CSS would relate to the event propagation in the original question?